# Change Web API URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My url is, for example:

```
http://localhost:10000
```

That's fine. My uri is 'api/Products'. Can I change the uri to something else, eg. 'myApp/Data/Products'?

Comment: Check app_Start folder for WebApiConfig.cs. There should be a defaultroute set up. You should be able to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the **Web API route config**, you should have the mapping there which looks something like...

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "API Default",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Try changing it to:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "API Default",
   routeTemplate: "myApp/Data/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Works great. How can I set which controllers point to 'myApp/Data/' and others to 'myApp/Modules/', etc?

Answer (score 0):

See App_Start folder in your project, and locate the WebApiConfig.cs file. In that file the routing for the WebAPI should be set up.

By default it would be something like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Try changing to:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "myApp/Data/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```